# audio recorded using ffmpeg alsa has very low volume in one channel

Tags: ffmpeg, alsa

I have recorded stereo mix on linux(Fedora 23) using below command.

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 48000 -i hw:1,2 -t 30 out.wav
```

Above command record whatever is being played on my machine but left channel has good audio and right one contain very low volume.

I checked capture setting using alsamixer where it has 100 for both
Any suggestion, what could be the problem?

Comment: Does using `arecord` on with the same input also result in the same issue?

Comment: yes i have tried arecord as well and it results in same issue

Comment: Now we know that the issue isn't due to `ffmpeg`. Unfortunately I know little about ALSA.